# Getting proportions from data sets in R

Tags: r, statistics

I have a data set called 'md' which consists of 40 numbers 1-6, I need to get the proportion that the number 1 appears in the list, I've been looking for ways to get proportions but none of which seem to be relevant to my data set, the proportion is easily calculable, however, it is required to be done in R.

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic question and you should read up on some introductory manuals, but you can simply do something like:

```
sum(x == 1)/length(x)
```

Or for all values at once like:

```
prop.table(table(x))
```

---

Here are both approaches with some sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(6, 40, TRUE)
sum(x == 1)/length(x)
# [1] 0.1

prop.table(table(x))
# x
#     1     2     3     4     5     6 
# 0.100 0.175 0.250 0.125 0.200 0.150
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the `mean` function

```
mean(x==1)
#[1] 0.1
```